# how to correctly save and restor instance state of Fragments in back stack?

Tags: android, fragment, back-stack

I have found many instances of a similar question but no answer unfortunately meets my requirements.

I have many  fragment  inside  an activity  and an object that I transmit from one fragment to another. This object will be modified by each fragment I want that when I go back in the backstack I recover the previous fragment instance and the previous version of the object I'am tried with onSaveInstanceState but apparently when backing up in a fragment onSaveInstanceState is not called

```
  override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    outState?.run {
        putParcelable("PRODUCT",Product)
    }

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}
```

Comment: In order to get a meaningful answer, you should post some code snippets.  I would suggest starting with your onCreates and onSaveInstanceStates.

Comment: Fragments aren't destroyed on the back stack, so the Fragment and any objects it contains will still be there. The only reason you'd need `onSaveInstanceState()` is if the whole activity is destroyed and recreated (such as when you rotate your device). What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

When you modify the fragment, you need to create a new one and `.replace` the old one.

```
    public BlankFragment modifyFragment() {
        int newVar = myVar; // your modified variable. Not the best example

        // you need to create a new instance of the fragment
        // everytime you modify your fragment so that you can replace the
        // one you want to go back to later
        BlankFragment blankFragment = BlankFragment.newInstance(++newVar);

        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.a_main_fl_root, blankFragment) // When you click back press. It will restore the replaced fragment.
                .addToBackStack(null) 
                .commit();

        return blankFragment; // the new fragment is returned so you can replace it again and again.
        // what I didn't include is how to get the instance of the replaced fragment when you click back press.
    }
```

There's no need for savedInstanceState because it's only used for when the activity gets destroyed and recreated.

Comment: But how can I save the old version of the Product object without the current fragment modifications and get it back when I go back to the previous fragment

Comment: Your product object's instance should be inside your fragment, right? That fragment you replaced will stay in the backstack along with the product object. You cannot save just the product object, you have to save the whole fragment.